# URL rewriting in order to use joomla SEF

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, joomla3.0

I'm very new to apache. I read and read docs, turn all conf files I found, but ...

While I'm root on the webserver, I read that in order to optimize apache2, it is not a good idea to use .htaccess files (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html).

OK, I read a lot of howtos about url_rewriting and htacess. I tried this code into my www.site.com virtualhost file :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName site.com
    ServerAlias www.site.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@site.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/www.site.com
    RewriteEngine On
    <directory />
          RewriteBase /var/www/www.site.com/
          RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
          RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
          RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|$
          RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
          RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
          RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
          Options FollowSymLinks
          AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Please note that RewriteBase has been tested with DocumentRoot value and '/', and that all the RewriteCond come form std_htaccess of latest Joomla! source code.

Apache2 launches well, the site is viewed online with no error, but the rewrite is not working as joomla SEF is not working :(
I'm totaly lost ... again ... and I need your help guys !

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the correct way is

```
<directory /var/www/www.site.com/>
              RewriteEngine On
              RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
              RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
              RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
              RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
              RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
              RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
              Options FollowSymLinks
              AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
```